# Python 2.7: Multiprocessing not doing anything

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to make a client in python. I'm trying to use multiprocessing to receive and send objects.

I use this to send messages (Entering nothing is supposed to display the messages sent by other clients):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
    wait = 'yes'
    message = raw_input('Enter message into chat (enter nothing to refresh chat): ')
    if message == '':
        wait = 'no'
        continue
    sock.sendall(message)
```

And I use this to receive messages:

```
def listen():
    global wait
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(255)
        while True:
            if wait == 'yes':
                continue
            print data
            break
```

And I use this to get listen() working:

```
q = multiprocessing.Process(target=listen)
q.start()
```

Am I missing anything or am I doing something wrong. Please help!

Comment: What is `sock`? It doesn't sound like your processes have a communication channel *to each other*; it sounds like they might be on the same end of a socket, or they might have unrelated sockets. We need a [mcve] to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you need two ends of a connection to be able to communicate.  It looks like you have one socket and it's not clear it's connected to anything (you omitted the socket setup code, so hard to say).

Try using socketpair() to get two sockets that are connected:

```
import socket
client, server = socket.socketpair()
```

Then use `client` in the main process and `server` in the "listening" process (or vice versa, it doesn't really matter).  The two sockets are connected and sending using one lets the *other* receive the data.

Comment: I checked on the python documentation but they said that this is only available on Unix. If I want to try to make a multi-platform program, how would I change this to be compatible with Windows? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's silly that Windows Python doesn't have `socketpair`.  Fortunately someone packaged it in a third-party library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.socketpair